# HSE06 band structure calculation in VASP stuck

Tags: vasp, hse06

I am performing the HSE06 band structure calculation after starting from pbe scf WAVECAR. The input file looks like this

```
 SYSTEM   =  Perovskite                                               
# Electronic minimization                                                                                                 
ISTART  = 1                                                            
ICHARG  = 0                                                            
ALGO    = Damped
PREC= Normal                                                                                                                                                                   
ENCUT   = 400                                                                                                                                                                    
NELM    = 200                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
EDIFF   = 1E-6                                                         
EDIFFG  =-0.03                                                         
LWAVE   =.FALSE.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
IVDW    = 11                                                           
VDW_S8 = 0.109                                                         
VDW_SR = 1.129                                                         
LORBIT  = 10                                                          
# Ionic minimization                                                                                                                                                                                                            
IBRION  = -1                                                           
ISIF    = 3                                                            
POTIM   = 0.5                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
# Exchange correlational functional                                                                                       
GGA = PE                                                               
LHFCALC = .TRUE.                                                       
HFSCREEN = 0.2                                                        
#Algo = Damped                                                                                                          
TIME = 0.4                                                             
ISMEAR   = 0                                                           
SIGMA    = 0.02                                                        
NCORE = 4                                                              
KPAR = 8
```

the calculation gets stuck before starting iterations. The OUTCAR shows

[image]

This exact INCAR has worked for the same system(with slightly different POSCAR, the space group remained same though). What could be the reason that the calculation gets stuck here?

Comment: I gave +1 long ago but: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411/5

Comment: usually when this kind of calculations get stuck without error, is due to memory requirements. Check how much memory request!